# CONCAT com erro

Tags: mysql, mysqli, select, concatenação-de-string

```
SELECT 

b.numero_contrato as name, CONCAT(
sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 'Concluida' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS concluidas,
sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 'Recebida' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS recebidas,
sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 'Autorizada' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS autorizadas) as dados

fROM controle_contratos a, contratos b where a.id_contrato = b.id_contrato and b.ativo = 1 group by b.numero_contrato
```

#1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'

Não consegui resolver esse erro, ajuda por favor.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat  segundo a documentação o `concat` recebe uma lista de valores separados por vírgula, o que não aconcece nesse  `case`. explique melhor o que quer fazer concatenando somas de valores diferentes, não faz muito sentido isso

Answer (score -1):

Na função `CONCAT`, você passa `CONCAT(Parametro A, PArametro B, Parametro C.....)` exemplo: `CONCAT(last_name, '''s job category is ')` onde vai exibir:

> Hall's job category is SA_REP'

Seu select esta tentando juntar CONCLUIDAS , RECEBIDAS e AUTORIZADAS.....

```
SELECT 

b.numero_contrato as name, CONCAT(
sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 'Concluida' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS concluidas,
sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 'Recebida' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS recebidas,
sum(CASE WHEN a.status = 'Autorizada' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS autorizadas) as dados

fROM controle_contratos a, contratos b where a.id_contrato = b.id_contrato and b.ativo = 1 group by b.numero_contrato
```

Acredito que a sentença abaixo te ajude:

```
SELECT 
    NAME, SUM(CONCLUIDAS), SUM(RECEBIDAS), SUM(AUTORIZADAS) 

FROM (

    SELECT 
        b.numero_contrato as name,  
        CASE WHEN a.status = 'Concluida' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as concluidas,
        CASE WHEN a.status = 'Recebida' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS recebidas,
        CASE WHEN a.status = 'Autorizada' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS autorizadas

    fROM 
        controle_contratos a, 
        contratos b 
    where
        a.id_contrato = b.id_contrato 
        and b.ativo = 1 

    group by b.numero_contrato
)
```